# Responsive CSS with columns set to 100% height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, multiple-columns

Setting up a vertical column page layout and wondering what your thoughts are on the best approach to do so in html/css. Below is some html and css starter code, but I'm looking for some help with getting the columns to line-up side by side with 100% height? Also this is a full screen (width) responsive fluid layout, with a fixed width on the left nav column.

In a nutshell... I'm coding [this](http://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/1972/screenshots/1323883/attachments/186271/discuss_144dpi.png) with the left columns falling off the smaller the browser windows get.

**Fullscreen view**

[image: fullscreen view]

**Portrait view**

[image: **portrait view**]

**Phone view**

[image: phone view]

**HTML**

```
<body>
<nav role="navigation">
    nav
</nav>
<main role="site">
    <article role="nav">
        list
    </article>
    <article role="main">
        content
    </article>
</main>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
nav[role=navigation]{
background-color: #aaa;
height: 100%;
width: 18em;
}
main{
width: 100%;
}
article[role=nav]{
background-color: #ddd;
height: 100%;
}
article[role=main]{
background-color: #efefef;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: No code to review yet, above is just so you understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: Not working. I'm looking for a solution in html/css to do what is in the pictures.

Comment: I don't know how experienced you are at HTML / CSS, so I'll just start broadly: You're going to want to use `@media queries` at each of those breakpoints for the different views. Regarding 3-column layouts, check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451142/a-clean-css3-3-column-layout-where-to-start) from StackOverflow for some helpful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working so that each vertical column can have it's own vertical overflow scrollbar and also so that the columns are floated (so that they can be easily added on the fly with html). The responsive part isn't in the demo.

[Check out the jsbin here.](http://jsbin.com/nuweh/1)

Thanks y'all for the comments/suggestions/ideas!

Answer (score 1):

height:100% never works for me but let's assume it does.
I think you can use percentage width and float:left for each column.

Since responsive design allows you to specify css for different screen sizes, you can change your percentages and make columns display:none for different screen size ranges.

Comment: In a nutshell... I'm coding [this](http://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/1972/screenshots/1323883/attachments/186271/discuss_144dpi.png) with the left columns falling off the smaller the browser windows get.

Answer (score 0):

This **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/qbRr4/)** doesn't do exactly what you want but it is close. It does the job of pinning the sidebar div to the left edge.

It will be difficult I think for you to manage the widths responsively if you use explicit width values like `18em` as you have in your code above. At least, it will until you specify which resolutions you want at each brea kpoint.

Comment: The left-nav is fixed, while the main is fluid. That's why the html is setup into two sections instead of three. At full-screen I'd like the left-nav displayed but at lower breakpoints I'm going to have it come out as a js side drawer. I was hoping to fix the nav at a explicit value and set the main to 100% of whatever is left. Then I'll figure out the breakpoints as I go.

Comment: BTW - your jsfiddle isn't displaying in columns (at least not in safari).

Comment: @Jeffrey I know; unfortunately I didn't have time to make the code work exactly as you wanted, but I think what I have in that JSFiddle is a good start (it separates the sidebar from the two divs and sticks it to the side at 100% height) for what you're asking.

Comment: I got it to have vertical columns with scrollbars, but the third column isn't allowing the background-color to go to 100% height. Also using negative margins, instead of floats, so unfortunately adding an additional column on the fly will be a pain. Do you have a solution for these? [Demo on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sekipaxi/1/)

Comment: No, but adding explicit values to the margins will indeed be trouble. Check out [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/Cheesetoast/pen/KFAaq) and [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5nR2/1/) for some ideas.

Comment: Finally got it working. [See it on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nuweh/1). Thanks y'all!