# Page Layout - Having picture tiles in 3 columns

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I've read the post [A clean CSS3 3-column layout, where to start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451142/a-clean-css3-3-column-layout-where-to-start), but I'm still experiencing problems with having a photo grid layout with 3 columns with the middle column a horizontal line.  However, I get the pictures laid out horizontally in left column and in the right column it is laid out more like a grid 2 x 2, but the picture sizes vary.

So, basically, I want to have 4 pictures in the left column laid as 2 x 2 all even sizes and the same for the right column in a compatible way (and if possible to add a column title as well).

My attempted approach is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Picture World</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >    
      </head>

      <body>

    <div id="header">   
     <header>

        <div id="header-left"><img src="/images/portal/logo.png" alt="logo" width="350" height="150"></div>
        <div id="header-right"><a href="/contactus">Contact Us</a></div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>   

    </header>

    </div>

        <h1>
            Welcome!  
        </h1>
    </div>

    <div id="nav">

        <div id="leftmenu">

            <p><a href="/home">Home</a></p>

            <p><a href="/aboutus">About Us</a></p>

            <p><a href="/ebook">E-Book</a></p>

            <p><a href="/emagazine">E-Magazine</a></p>

            <p><a href="/links">Links</a></p>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="leftmainsection">

    <div class="img">
      <a href="/ebook/001.pdf"> <img src="images/books/001.jpg" alt="Book 1"></a>
      <div class="desc">Author 1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="img">
      <a href="/ebook/002.pdf"> <img src="images/books/002.jpg" alt="Book 2"></a>
      <div class="desc">Author 2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="img">
      <a href="/ebook/003.pdf"> <img src="images/books/003.jpg" alt="Book 3"></a>
      <div class="desc">Author 3</div>
    </div>

    <div class="img">
      <a href="/ebook/004.pdf"> <img src="images/books/004.jpg" alt="Book 4"></a>
      <div class="desc">Author 4</div>
    </div>


      <div id="horizontal">
      </div>

      <div id="rightmainsection">


      <div class="img">
      <a href="/emagazine/001.pdf"> <img src="images/magazines/d001.jpg" alt="Book 1"></a>
      <div class="desc">Mag 1</div>
      </div>

      <div class="img">
      <a href="/emagazine/002.pdf"> <img src="images/magazines/d002.jpg" alt="Book 2"></a>
      <div class="desc">Mag 2</div>
      </div>

      <div class="img">
      <a href="/emagazine/003.pdf"> <img src="images/magazines/d003.jpg" alt="Book 3"></a>
      <div class="desc">Mag 3</div>
     </div>

      <div class="img">
      <a href="/emagazine/004.pdf"> <img src="images/magazines/d004.jpg" alt="Book 4"></a>
      <div class="desc">Mag 4</div>
      </div>

      </div>

      <div id="footer">

        <footer>
            <div id="footer-left">Copyright &copy; 2016 PWC Ltd</div>
            <div id="footer-right"><a href="/contactus">Contact Us</a></div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>   

        </footer>

    </div>


      </div>


      </body>
    </html>
```

And my CSS is:

```
    body {
        background: white;  
    }

    .content {
        padding: 25px;
    }


    #header-left {
        float: left;
    }

    #header-right {
        float: right;
    }

    #header-centre {
        overflow: hidden;
    }


    #header {
        background-color:white;
        color:black;
        /* text-align:center; */
        padding:5px;
    }

    #nav {
        line-height:30px;
        background-color:white;
        height:400px;
        width:100px;
        float:left;
        padding:5px; 
    }

    .sidemenu {
        width: 25%;
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }


    #leftbodysection {
        width:50px;
        float:left;
        padding:10px; 
    }
    #rightbodysection {
        width:50px;
        float:right;
        padding:10px; 
    }
    #footer {
        background-color:blue;
        color:white;
        clear:both;
        text-align:center;
        padding:5px; 
    }


    #footer-left {
        float: left;
    }

    #footer-right {
        float: right;
    }

    #footer-centre {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #horizontal {
        line-height:30px;
        background-color:white;
        height:400px;
        width:20px;
        float:left;
        padding:5px; 
    }

    hr { 
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0.5em;
        margin-bottom: 0.5em;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border-style: inset;
        border-width: 1px;
    }


    div.img {
        margin: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        float: left;
        width: 180px;
    }   

    div.img:hover {
        border: 1px solid #777;
    }

    div.img img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    div.desc {
        padding: 15px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

How can I solve this please?

Comment: you paste `html` code again instead of `css`

Comment: Thanks, just noticed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way example:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>


    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="column-center"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
        <div class="column-left"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
        <div class="column-right"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.column-left{ 
    float: left; 
    width: 33%; 

    }
.column-right{ 
    float: right;
    width: 33%;

    }
.column-center{ 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in your example, even though it does appear to be in 3 columns, however, the the pictures in 3rd column start displaying lower in the column, that is, the point where the last pictures end in columns 1 and 2.  Any fix there?  Also, how would I put a horizontal line between the columns and possibly having title headings for each column?

Comment: I fixed the part that had the last (3rd) column start displaying lower in the page by reducing width size of 33% by just 1% to 32%.  Thanks.

Comment: Note: In my first comment, I meant to say: how would I put a vertical line between the columns and having title headings for each column?

Answer (score 2):

Two simple ways to achieve this:

**1- A Simple Flex Grid of Images (33.3% width):**

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */    
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around; /* Safari 6.1+ */    
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.container div {
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 calc(33.3% - 20px); /* Safari 6.1+ */
  -ms-flex: 0 0 calc(33.3% - 20px); /* IE 10 */ 
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.3% - 20px);  
  background: lavender;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
</div>
```

*ps: `-20px` on the example `calc(33.3% - 20px);` means 2 times the margin value (which is `10px`)*

**2- CSS Multiple Columns:**

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 10px; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.container div {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;  
  background: lavender;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=img></div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grvPjd?editors=1100)

*ps2: my suggestion is to use `@media queries` to let it become a 2 or 1 column grid on small devices.*

> Source: [**w3schools**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would like more control over what goes in each column - any suggestions there?  Moreover, I tried your example with 8 pictures: the first 6 pictures appears in 3 columns, but the last two pictures at the bottom goes out of sync with the columns.

Comment: @Jamie answer edited with a very different method; I hope it can be more useful than the earlier one.

Comment: I've tried your new answer, but in Firefox, all 12 pictures are in one column.  Any other suggestions?  Also, how would I add a heading title for each column and also control how many images for each column - how could that be done?  I may for example, want 4 images in each column.  Thanks.

Comment: [**this is how it looks like on my firefox 45**](https://i.gyazo.com/5b1d2e2b0a106c3324ee195cef0ac865.png)

Comment: warning: you must set the images size with percentages example `width:100%` `height:auto` instead of pixels.

Comment: Codepen DEMO: [**working example with big pictures**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grvPjd?editors=1100) notice the pictures are set with `width:100%` and `vertical-align:middle`

Comment: _ps: I did make an update on the answer snippets with this img size info plus the Codepen with big pictures_

Comment: Here is snippet that is integrated into your solution, but I am still getting all pictures in one column in Firefox:  
  
  <div class="container">
   
  <div class="img">
    <a href="/ebook/001.pdf"> <img src="images/books/001.jpg" alt="Book 1" width="300" height="200"></a>
    <div class="desc">Author 1</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="img">
    <a href="/ebook/002.pdf"> <img src="images/books/002.jpg" alt="Book 2" width="300" height="200"></a>
    <div class="desc">Author 2</div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- And so on for all the other pictures -->

 </div>

Comment: And here's also the CSS snippet regarding the img part that's in addition to your CSS code: 

  div.img {
      margin: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      float: left;
      /* width: 180px; */
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
  } 
  
  div.img:hover {
      border: 1px solid #777;
  }
  
  div.img img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
  }
  
  div.desc {
      padding: 15px;
      text-align: center;
  }

Comment: @Jamie I said you cant use pixels as the width and height (except in max-width / max-height). The gallery itself is right but youre placing the images in the wrong way.

Comment: **remove** `width="300" height="200"` **must be** `<img src="images/books/001.jpg" alt="Book 1">`

Comment: **remove** `width: 180px;` aswell. You can use `max-width: 180px` or `max-width:300px` (if you want a limit) instead.

Comment: I've applied your changes, but still it's not working properly, but at least it's in 2 columns now. I've now added the full CSS to my question (as I had accidentally duplicated the HTML code). You really deserve that I tick your answer as you've really put lots of effort to helping me out here, however, I'm still struggling to get things working and also I think that with this new slick solution you can't have columns heading and control the number of images per column, right? Hence, I'm for now going down the path of the other answer here in which I've made significant progress. Thanks again.

Comment: good luck with the project; It's a good idea to let the full path of the images avaible on the next questions since it can produce a different result at the end (as we see on this post); see ya;

Comment: about the number of items on each column, i think it isnt possible with pure css; you'll probably need javascript to build your gallery;